# Unit circle circumferential length on a Beltrami pseudosphere

Tags: differential-geometry

What is the perimeter length of a geodesic circle of unit radius of tangential curvature?  .. assuming that the circle lies entirely on one side of its cuspidal equator.

Comment: In hyperbolic geometry the circumference of a circle of radius r is
 $ \frac {2 \pi } {\sqrt{-K}} \sinh( \sqrt{-K }r) $ so in your case  $  2 \pi   \sinh(1) $  is $  \pi  (e - e^{-1}) $

Comment: @Willemien: This is classical from Gauss direct OK, but has it been verified by computer graphics in recent times? Any references? Or do we say it is too basic in hyperbolic geometry so unnecessary to verify?

Comment: Nothing is ever to basic, (and indeed the formulas are copied from   wikipedia-hyperbolic Geometry) it is more a problem of how to verify it by computer graphics? (everything is bent in this problem so counting squares won't work)